Changing the field of an irreducible representation leaves it irreducible.
I am currently learning representation theory of finite groups over arbitrary fields.
I've encountered an interesting result multiple times but never found a proof of it anywhere.
Let $E/F$ be a field extension, $V$ be an $E$-representation and $W$ be an $F$-representation.
Then $W$ can be seen as an $E$-representation by extension of the base field $($i.e. $W \otimes_{F} E$ admits a natural structure of $E$-representation$)$.
The $V$ can be seen as an $F$-representation by seeing it as an $F$-vector space.
We say that an $E$-representation $V$ can be realized over $F$ if there exists an $F$-representation $W$ such that $V$ is isomorphic to $W \otimes_{F} E$.

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and $V$ be an irreducible $E$-representation of a finite group $G$.
If $V$ is not realized over any intermediate field $K$ of $E/F$, then $V$ stays irreducible as an $F$-representation of $G$.

This can be easily proven in the case where $E = \mathbb{C}$ and $F = \mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is of degree $2$.

Let $V$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representation and $W$ an irreducible sub-$\mathbb{R}$-representation of $V$.
Since $W$ is irreducible, either $W \cap iW = 0$ or $W \cap iW = W$.
But by definition, $W + iW$ is a sub-$\mathbb{C}$-representation of $V$ and is therefore equal to $V$.
If $W \cap iW = W$ then $W = V$ and so $V$ is irreducible when seen as an $\mathbb{R}$-representation.
If $W \cap iW = 0$ then we have $V = W \oplus iW = W \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ and therefore $W$ is a realization of $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to do same demonstration by induction for the general case but I am stuck.
I am looking for a reference where this question is studied.

What's wrong with doing the same thing? Choose a basis $B$ for $E$ as an $F$-vector space then take $\sum_{b\in B} bW$ if $W$ is an $E$-subrepresentation of $V$. So just mimic the $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R$ case?

@DavidA.Craven: you’re the group theorist, so you know best. But why should the various $bW$ be in direct sum?

The first question is did you want $E/F$ to be finite?

I don’t think that’s correct, but neither do I know a counter-example (is there a representation $V$ of a group $G$ that can be defined on two number fields $X,Y$ that are linearly disjoint with distinct degrees over the field generated by the character of $V$? Such a representation would be a counter-example.)
[see edit for the counterexample]
Suppose for the sake of simplicity that the character of $V$ has values in $F$ and let $W$ be an irreducible component of $V$ as a representation of $G$ over $F$.
Now, $W \otimes_F E$ is contained in $V \otimes_F E$, whose character as an $E$-representation is a multiple of the character of $V$. Hence $W \otimes_F E$ is isomorphic to a sum of copies of $V$.
The number of copies of $V$ in $W \otimes_F E$ is the Schur index $\sigma$ of $V$, which is also the minimal degree of an extension of $F$ over which $V$ is defined.
Now, $V$ is irreducible as an $F$-representation iff $\dim_F\,W= \dim_F\,V$, iff $\dim_E\,(W \otimes_F E)=[E:F]\dim_E\, V$, iff $\sigma\dim_E\,V=[E:F]\dim_E\,V$, iff $\sigma=[E:F]$, iff $V$ is not defined over any extension of $F$ of lower degree than $E$.
This doesn’t imply your criterion (except when $[E:F]=2$), because as far as I know there’s no “smallest field over which a representation is defined” in general.
For instance, the “Artin representation” of the Galois group of a finite extension of $p$-adic fields (see Chapter 19 of Serre’s Linear Representations of Finite Groups) is, if I recall correctly, defined over $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ for any $\ell \neq p$ but not known (I think?) defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Edit: a counter-example. (thanks to David A. Craven for the reference).
In the article Minimal splitting fields for group representations by Fein, an irreducible representation $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /n})$ of a group $G$ of order $n$ is constructed such that, if $F$ denotes the number field generated by the values of its character, there is no subextension $F \subset L \subset \mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /n})$ on which $L$ is defined and such that $L/F$ is the Schur index $m_V$ of $V$.
Let $E/F$ be a minimal subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /n})/F$ on which $V$ can be constructed. We consider a realization $V_E$ of $V$ over $E$.
Let $W$ be an irreducible component of $V_E$ (as a representation of $G$ over $F$). Then the unedited part shows that $W \otimes_F E$ is the direct sum of $m_V$ copies of $V_E$. In particular, $\dim_F\,{W}=m_V\dim_E\,V_E< \dim_F\, V_E$, whence $V_E$ is not irreducible as a representation of $G$ over $F$.
Yet, $V$ cannot be realized over any proper subfield of $E$.

There is definitely no minimal field of definition in general. The easiest example is the $2$-dimensional representation of the quaternion group $Q_8$, which is defined over $\mathbb Q(i)$, but also over infinitely many other quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$.

One way to salvage the statement is if there are smallest degrees of definition in the sense of divisibility. For precisely, if for any representation $V$ with character values in $F$, there is an integer $d$ such that if $V$ is realizable over some extension $E/F$, then $V$ is realizable over some subextension $E’/F$ of degree $d$ of $E/F$. I expect (with low confidence) this to be false, do you know a counter-example (or is this in fact true?).

If I have read this correctly, you are just asking that every field over which a representation is defined contains a subfield that is a degree $d$ extension over the field of values of the character, where $d$ is the Schur index. This is false, in general, as proved in a paper of Fein, 'Minimal splitting fields for group representations'.

That’s what I was asking for, thank you! This directly yields a counter-example to the OP’s claim. By the way, do you know if the Schur index must divide the degree of any extension over which the representation is defined, or is this also false?

This should be true. Thinking about central simple algebras, then I think it's a result of Brauer and Noether that the degree of a splitting field of a central simple algebra is always a multiple of the degree of a minimal splitting field.
